# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'DialogRef<TwoButtonPreset>'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, typescript, updating

Hi i'm trying to run this code on Angular 6 after updating from angular2-modal to ngx-modialog

```
this.modal.confirm()
            .showClose(true)
            .title(this.translator.instant('common.message.confirm.delete'))
            .keyboard(27)
            .okBtn(this.translator.instant('common.text.yes'))
            .cancelBtn(this.translator.instant('common.text.no'))
            .message("<h5>" + this.translator.instant('common.message.confirm.deleteAll') + "</h5>")
            .open()
            .then(( d ) => d.result 
            .then(( r ) => {...});
```

but after compiling i get this error :

```
Property 'then' does not exist on type 'DialogRef<TwoButtonPreset>'.ts(2339)
```

I tried this but same error

```
... 
dialog: DialogRef<TwoButtonPreset>; 
... 
let dialog = this.modal.confirm() .showClose(true)
.title(this.translator.instant('common.message.confirm.delete')) 
.keyboard(27) 
.okBtn(this.translator.instant('common.text.yes')) 
.cancelBtn(this.translator.instant('common.text.no')) 
.message("<h5>" + this.translator.instant('common.message.confirm.deleteAll') + "</h5>") 
.open() 
.then(( d ) => d.result 
...
```

I also tried that but getting `; expected`

```
this.modal.confirm()
            .showClose(true)
            .title(this.translator.instant('common.message.confirm.delete'))
            .keyboard(27)
            .okBtn(this.translator.instant('common.text.yes'))
            .cancelBtn(this.translator.instant('common.text.no'))
            .message("<h5>" + this.translator.instant('common.message.confirm.deleteAll') + "</h5>")
            .open()
            .result => {...};
```

Here's my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "frontend6",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/alertify": "^0.3.29",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.25",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.47",
    "@types/openlayers": "4.6.9",
    "ag-grid": "7.1.0",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "7.1.2",
    "angular-tree-component": "^3.7.3",
    "angular2-google-maps": "0.17.0",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.4",
    "angular2-text-mask": "2.1.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "^8.0.0",
    "angular2-tree-component": "2.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "chroma-js": "^1.3.7",
    "codemirror": "5.22.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "flot": "0.8.0-alpha",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.1.0",
    "highcharts": "^6.2.0",
    "highcharts-stock": "^0.1.7",
    "jqcloud2": "2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "2.4.0",
    "jquery.browser": "0.1.0",
    "jquery.flot.tooltip": "0.9.0",
    "jspdf": "1.3.5",
    "jspdf-autotable": "2.3.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "modernizr": "^3.11.1",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "mydatepicker": "1.10.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.1.16-11",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-data-table": "1.0.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.1.4-2",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "0.7.7",
    "ng2-select": "1.1.2",
    "ng2-table": "1.3.2",
    "ng2-tag-input": "0.7.0",
    "ng2-validation": "3.1.3",
    "ngx-modialog": "^5.0.1",
    "openlayers": "3.20.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "screenfull": "3.0.2",
    "simple-line-icons": "2.4.1",
    "spinkit": "1.2.5",
    "summernote": "0.8.2",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "weather-icons": "1.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/codemirror": "0.0.37",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/moment": "2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-read-json": "1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "loaders.css": "0.1.2",
    "napa": "2.3.0",
    "protractor": "4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5",
    "webpack": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.9"
  }
}
```

The base app was on Angular 2 i was able to upgrade it to Angular 4 now I'm going for Angular 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by  adding `result` before `then` :

```
... 
this.modal.confirm().showClose(true)
.title(this.translator.instant('common.message.confirm.delete')) 
.keyboard(27) 
.okBtn(this.translator.instant('common.text.yes')) 
.cancelBtn(this.translator.instant('common.text.no')) 
.message("<h5>" + this.translator.instant('common.message.confirm.deleteAll') + "</h5>") 
.open()
.result
.then(( d ) => d.result 
...
```

Comment: If our answers fixed your problem, please mark them as correct

Answer (score 1):

I guess `open()` does not return a Promise. Try to add `.result` like this:

```js
...
.open().result => alert(`The result is: ${result}`) );
...
```

(This is for v4)

Comment: getting ```; expected``` can you check my modified post

Comment: are you using v3 or v4?

Comment: Im using Angular 6

Comment: And this library: https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ngx-modialog ?

Comment: `"ngx-modialog": "^5.0.1"`

Comment: I added the package.json if it can help

Answer (score 1):

you need to reference the dialogRef itself,

```
dialogRef.result
        .then( result => alert(`The result is: ${result}`) );
```

Comment: i tried as mentionned in the editted post but not working